# How to Share Common JS Code within Multiple VS Website Projects

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio

I'm looking for the best approach to using Visual Studio to manage the development and organization of multiple websites that would share common JS/CSS/Html/Image files. However all have the possibility of unique or differing functionality, so somehow mimicking inheritance would be ideal.

We develop in the absence of a framework, just straight up shtml and JS. No C#. No DLLs in play.

Our existing website-project has been running well for the better part of 2 years now... But we're now introducing 3 new clients to the mix - thus this post.

It is time (probably passed time) to slice things up in common vs. client buckets so individual adjustments can be made without adversely affecting other applications.

I have spent some time in VS looking for the right project combination to get us there. I've looked into solution folders and shared projects. But spinning up a new empty website-project and trying to reference these has failed. They may play nice with C# code, but that's not what I have. Simply trying to reference a .js-file in a shared location from a html page gives me a 404.

I'm open to anything that will result in a single common code base, with the ability to override on a client basis (if possible).

If the best approach is to simply continue with a single website-project and maintain client folders, I can work with that. I may simply need some guidance on how to "publish" the appropriate file set per client as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

For common css/js I would suggest you create a sort of a style-guide. Create a CDN-like project if you have the means. In simple terms you can just have a public web project and have your common css and js hosted there. Then you can access them by URL (CDN style), without any sort of auth. Keep in mind, this will make the css and js public more or less, if people really wanted to get to it.

Then you can manage this cdn project whenever css and js changes come through.

In the end, you just create a new project for said client, draw up the html, and then import your shared css/js. Then in the new project you can also manage any project specific styles and javascript there, independent of the shared cdn stuff.

Edit:

The only thing I can think of to solve the html issue in a vanilla web project is to use either a templating library like knockout.js or write your own javascript library that can read in a page of html and grab blocks in your CDN then you can ajax call these functions to grab the code blocks asynchronously.

I think what I don't really understand is if you're going to always use the exact same HTML or if you'll be changing it up. Because if its all the exact same, I dont see the need for multiple projects even. If only SOME of the code is going to be the same, then I think you would need a templating system in place.

Comment: Awesome response. We've been discussing this too. And while this may end up being the approach for shared JS and CSS, it doesn't solve the issue of shared HTML. I appreciate the fact that what I'm asking/looking for may not be possible, but I can't imagine we're the only ones in this boat. Thanks again!

Comment: @Matt I edited the answer to provide more information.